# Iframe not showing correctly, black frame too big

Tags: html, iframe

I am embedding this:

```
<iframe src='https://www.embed.com/app/math-game/' style='width: 800px; height: 600px;' scrolling='no' frameBorder='0'></iframe>
```

but I see a small game with a huge black frame,
how could I embed just the game without that black frame?

Here is the page:

https://www.sinapsi.org/wordpress/gioco/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because what you embedded does not support Width and Height Given. You could do one Thing to enlarge. Use CSS with the iframe to make it compatible with Mobile as well as Desktop. Remove `style='width: 800px; height: 600px;'`
CSS

```
canvas#cnvs   {
  width: 180px;
  height: 80px;
  background: url("https://yourcompany/yourlogo.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Take the width and all things according. I have shared a sample to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, but I do not understand where put that code.

Comment: Its given as a css file. SO you are a newbie and So I am guiding you from start. Put <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head> in Your HTML code. Then create a styles.css in the same HTML root folder. Paste the above given code in that and remember, do not give any HTML code inside .css file. Hope it helps! If not, I am here to help

Comment: This method is known as external css so you could probably search for this type of videos. if you are on wordpress, Install any css plugin and paste the code for the given page

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that I am using Wordpress and a page in it. So I have to change the css for all wordpress pages or for only that one? I know how add additional CSS in wordpress theme.

Comment: Then also you can add in appearance. It will work and not create problems for all iframes

Comment: Eventually I got what I needed using this code: <div style="width: 950px; height: 540px; overflow: hidden;"><iframe style="width: 1000px; height: 600px; margin: 100px 0px 0px -180px;" src="embed.com/app/math-game/"></iframe></div>

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container iframe {
  width: 950px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -175px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe src='https://www.embed.com/app/math-game/'></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not understand how use your suggestion. If I write the second part of the code in my page I get a small game: https://www.sinapsi.org/wordpress/gioco/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an external stylesheet, you can use this code

```html
<div style="width:600px;height:450px;overflow:hidden;">
  <iframe src='https://www.embed.com/app/math-game/' style="width:961px;height:700px;margin:0px 0px 0px -185px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the code you wrote but the result is as small as ever: https://www.sinapsi.org/wordpress/gioco/

Comment: Eventually I got what I needed using this code: <div style="width: 950px; height: 540px; overflow: hidden;"><iframe style="width: 1000px; height: 600px; margin: 100px 0px 0px -180px;" src="https://www.embed.com/app/math-game/"></iframe></div>